# Chrome extension url block filter not taking dynamic data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making an extension to get URL from server and block those

```js
var BlockUrl=[];
function doSomthing(data){
      BlockUrl=data
    }
function loadXMLDoc(){
      $.get('http://localhost:3000/blocker',(data)=>{
          doSomthing(data)
      })
      
    }

loadXMLDoc();
console.log(BlockUrl)
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener( 
  info => {  
          
          
            return {cancel: true};
          
},
  
  {urls: BlockUrl},
  ["blocking"]
);
```

But the log is undefined because on asynchronous call. what should I do to resolve it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I can't get data because it gives undefined because of asynchronous function. I don't know what to do